# How do I get divs to vertically align in the most compact manner?

Tags: javascript, html, css, vertical-alignment

### Edit

As to why I need this behaviour, having my content in a single div means that all of the content is in chronological order on both the web page and in the html. This means that when the content is shown on a small screen and the columns collapse into a single one, the content is still in chronological order.

```
                1 div -->  1                2 divs  -->  1
                1 | 2      2                1 | 2        3
                3 | 4      3                3 | 4        5
                5 |        4                5 |          2
                           5                             4
```

---

On my [website](http://trojandev.proggle.net/java-help.php) I have two columns of content, each taking up 50% of the width. The content is organised into boxes which can be toggled to hide/show content when you click on their header.

When a box on the right is minimised, the box below it fills the gap that was created, leaving the correct spacing: [image]

However when a box on the left is minimised a gap is left between it and the next box, relative to the size of the neighbouring box on the right:

[image]

Some pseudo code for the div arrangement:

```
<div class="full_width">
    <div class="box">       <-- box 1
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">       <-- box 2
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">       <-- box 3
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is my understanding that in this case box 3 will can not be positioned above the bottom of box 2 due to the order of content in the html, is there any way around this?

I'd be happy with a javascript solution as this can only be a problem on pages that have javascript enabled.

### Notes

-You'll need javascript and a monitor wider than 1000px to view the issue live on my website as the columns collapse into 1 below that width and the hide/show functionality is provided by javascript.

-I could get around this by having two separate columns of content which cannot change sides, however that is not the functionality I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this function and call it when the page first loads, and then whenever a box finishes changing size, a surprisingly simple function.

```
function column_align() {
    $('.box').each(function() {
        // if box on left of screen
        if ($(this).offset().left < 50) {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        } else {
            $(this).css("float", "right")
        }
    });
}
```

Where before we had this alignment problem: [image]

The boxes fit snugly, and in the correct order down the page: [image]

Answer (score 3):

Why not leverage CSS3 columns? The benefit of the below is they will also collapse responsively at lower screen sizes (you'll likely want to change the below to suit our purposes):

HTML

```
<div class='full_width'>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
        <h1>Heading</h1>
        <div>Content.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.full_width{
    -webkit-column-width: 20em;
    -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-width: 20em;
    -moz-column-gap: 2em;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -ms-column-width: 20em;
    -ms-column-gap: 2em;
    -ms-column-count: 2;
    column-width: 20em;
    column-gap: 2em;
    column-count: 2;
}
.box{
    break-inside: avoid-column;
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    width:100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: I've /really/ tried to get this working but the behaviour is so unintuitive... It messed with how tall the page thinks it is, in a seemingly random way, it sometimes cuts random sections of content in the left column and puts them into the right column, except when it does, it ignores where the column starts and it also ignores my old responsive code that collapsed the columns into a single column when the page was too narrow.

Comment: Its quite hard to solve your problems without the wider code you have in your page. Just taking the above and putting it in e.g. jsfiddle, the noted behaviour doesnt occur. There may be other conflicting styles at work here :(

Comment: The rest of my page is actually quite unobtrusive, I couldn't see it interfering, I have very close to exactly what you have written above, also I can recreate a number of the issues that I'm facing, in a jsfiddle. The order of elements is wrong and the right column ignores padding: http://jsfiddle.net/Troyseph/ng0pkoqr/

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't want 2 separate divs, one per column ? This would work only on CSS-side, and you either would be able to invert left to right.

Comment: If there was a separate div, one per column, then content would not be able to change sides.

Comment: For future reference, your answer here would have been better as a comment on the question, as opposed to an answer =]